# Azure Mobile Services __includeDeleted = false custom Parameters

Tags: android, azure, push, azure-mobile-services, pull

In my android app while synchronizing, I don't want to get the deleted records.
According to this url: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/issues/573
, __includeDeleted = true, is set by default in the query. How can i append custom parameters in order to set __includeDeleted=false?

Thank you!